# Create a product using Magento REST API 1.x gives 401 and product gets created

Tags: magento-1.9, rest-api

I have admin role access to Magento REST API with full access to all the attributes.

Upon creating a product the response code returned is 401 and there is no response body. How do I get the recently created product id or a valid response code like 201 or 200 ?

Is there any configuration required for that ? What is the expected behaviour?

Comment: If I use a similar request from Postman REST client I get a response body as `{"messages":{"error":[{"code":401,"message":"oauth_problem=nonce_used"}]}}`

Comment: the product gets created though

Comment: Ever find a solution to this? Having the same issue. Turns out that Magento is validating the noonce twice.